# Bootstrap .jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made this landing page which worked fine. The background image covered the page and it looked great. I left it and came back a day later and it looks different. I can't see the reason for it. The image wont appear behind the text at all only in the header (check the picture).   [image: current landing page]

```
 <body>  
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
                <img src="images/logo1.png" class="logo img-responsive" align="right">
            </div>
          </div>

<!-- featured content -->
        <div class="featured">

<!--  row for grid system / limit space taken by featured content -->
        <div class="row">

<!-- use only 9 columns out of 12 for medium and large devices -->
        <div class="col-md-9">

              <h1> Christopher McConney</h1> <br> <br>
              <h3> A creative front end web developer <br> Specialising in responsive and dynamic web pages</h3><br><br>
              <p>
              <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="index.html"> Find out more </a>  
              </p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
<!-- footer-->
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p align="right"> &copy; Developed by Christopher McConney 2018 </p> 
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
.jumbotron {
    background: url(images/background.jpeg) center center ;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/*logo position and size*/
.logo{
    width:85px;
    height:65px;
}

.jumbotron logo{
margin-right: 30px;   
margin-top: 10px;
}

/*set text colour*/
.featured{ 
    color:lightgrey;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

/* space between logo and title */
.featured h1{
    padding-top: 60px
}

/*style button*/

.featured .btn-default{
    font-weight:bold;
    color: lightgrey;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    align-content:center
}

/*style footer*/
.footer{
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color:darkgray;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding:10px; 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: The `align` attribute is deprecated, use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that your `.featured` div needs to be nested inside your `.jumbotron` which has the background image. Currently you have it nested outside of the `.jumbotron`.

The new markup would look like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="images/logo1.png" class="logo img-responsive" align="right">

        <div class="featured">

            <!--  row for grid system / limit space taken by featured content -->
            <div class="row">

                <!-- use only 9 columns out of 12 for medium and large devices -->
                <div class="col-md-9">

                    <h1> Christopher McConney</h1> <br> <br>
                    <h3> A creative front end web developer <br> Specialising in responsive and dynamic web pages</h3><br><br>
                    <p>
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="index.html"> Find out more </a>
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- featured content -->

<!-- footer-->
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p align="right"> &copy; Developed by Christopher McConney 2018 </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will also correctly place your Bootstrap `.row` inside the `.container` like it's suppose to be.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you closed your jumbotron DIV early. This is what you have:

```
 <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
            <img src="images/logo1.png" class="logo img-responsive" align="right">
        </div>
      </div>
```

Move both `</div>` above after the `.featured` DIVs closing tag.